# Change Default Theme colour

Tags: android

I am using Theme.Holo.Light how to change default colour of theme.
With the help of style.
Following is my theme

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>
```

Comment: where is your theme??

Comment: Wow! the shortest style file I've ever seen!

Comment: <style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

Comment: plz provide solution

Comment: There's no custom style defined in your custom style...

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
</style>
```

You can use theme editor to set all kinds of colors.
[image]

Comment: i m using eclipse,how to do in eclipse